# Value from DropDownListFor is not saving value to Database

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Here is my view

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SubCatagory, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SubCatagory, new SelectList(ViewBag.SubCategories, "Id", "Name", "Category"))
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SubCatagory, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```

And here is the method where I'm saving data.

```
 dbContext.Products.Add(product);
 dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

It is saving all the values to database except SubCatagoryId..
Can anyone please help me ?

Comment: Does `product` have a property `SubCategoryId` and is it populated as expected when you run the debugger? Do you get an error? If so what is the error? Please show us a more complete code example with your action and model.

Comment: @Sajid8212, Show your `Product` model class please?

Comment: public class Product
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Product Name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Selling Price")]
        public double SellingPrice { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Sub Catagory")]
        public SubCatagory SubCatagory { get; set; }

        public double Quantity { get; set; }

        public QuantityType QuantityType { get; set; }     }

Comment: Here is my Product class...

Answer (score 1):

The `SubCatagory` property contains null value because it's a complex object property bound for `SubCatagory` class, which `DropDownListFor` returns single selected value instead of entire class properties. You should do one of these:

**Option A: Create selected value property**

Create an `int` property which will hold selected value from `DropDownListFor` on `Product` class, and then you can assign `SubCatagory` property inside controller by querying from database based from passed value in newly created property.

**Model**

```
public class Product 
{ 
    [Key] 
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Sub Catagory")] 
    public int SelectedSubCatagory { get; set; }

    // other properties
}
```

**View**

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SelectedSubCatagory, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedSubCatagory, new SelectList(ViewBag.SubCategories, "Id", "Name", "Category"))
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SelectedSubCatagory, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```

**Option B: Use existing child property of `SubCatagory` class**

Suppose you have ID property declared inside `SubCatagory` class like this:

```
public class SubCatagory
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    // other properties
}
```

You may use it to bind on `DropDownListFor` helper as in example below:

**View**

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SubCatagory.Id, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SubCatagory.Id, new SelectList(ViewBag.SubCategories, "Id", "Name", "Category"))
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SubCatagory.Id, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```

Note that if you take this option, make sure that `SubCatagory` property is already instantiated (with `new` keyword) in `Product` class to avoid `NullReferenceException` when using its child properties.

Reference:

[How to simple Html.DropDownListFor MVC.NET (Nested Viewmodels)](https://agilewarrior.wordpress.com/2012/12/13/how-to-simple-html-dropdownlistfor-mvc-net/)